# Where is the "Untouchable" trait from?

Tags: content-identification, warhammer-40k

I ran into this trait while looking for information on blanks and while there are several sites that mention it I can't seem to identify which book it is from. Does anyone know where this trait is from?

> UNTOUCHABLE (X) (TRAIT)
> Prerequisites: Character Creation Only, Must Not Possess a Psy Rating
>
> Untouchables have no presence in the warp and inhibit psychic energy in the immediate area. This Trait has different levels of effect. The number in parentheses indicates the Untouchable’s level of power.
>
> Psychic Invulnerability: An Untouchable is completely immune to Psychic Powers and Psychic energy and effects directed against them (as well as special abilities used by creatures with the Daemonic Trait, the Warp Weapon Quality, possession, sorcery, Corruption Points from warp shock, and so forth). Untouchables cannot be detected by means of Psyniscience and similar abilities. Powers of this type directed at an Untouchable, even if successfully manifested, simply fail. If an Untouchable is caught in the effect of a Psychic Power, Psychic Phenomena, or Perils of the Warp over a wide area, it simply fails to affect him, although it may affect other people normally, subject to the Psychic Disruption effect, below.
>
> Psychic Disruption: All Psychic Powers manifested within a radius equal to the Untouchable’s Willpower Bonus in metres reduce their effective Psy Rating by the level of the Untouchable Trait (X).
>
> Additionally, creatures subject to Warp Instability suffer double Damage from its effects while in this area.

Comment: No idea what books it's from, but that's a less common term for [the ability](https://warhammer40k.fandom.com/wiki/Blank_(Psychic)) than I've seen in other sources. They're usually called Blanks or Nulls, with the trait itself being referred to as the Pariah Gene.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is from *[Rogue Trader - The Navis Primer](http://www.cold-moon.com/40k/40kRP/RTCampaign/PDFs/Rogue%20Trader%20-%20The%20Navis%20Primer.pdf)*, p. 85. It is a trait of the Untouchable Elite Advance.